# How can I update table A with data from table C when A and C are linked via table B

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have three tables(`A`, `B`, and `C`) and would like to update null values in `A.appointment_id` with values in `C.tc_appointment_id`.  Table `A` and `C` can be joined via table `B`.  Blue arrows represent joins, the red arrow represents the update I am trying to achieve.

[image: Visual]

I am able to join the three tables together and have tried to modify my select statement into an update.  My successful select statement and unsuccessful update follow.

```
--Working select

select A.tc_ASN_id,A.appointment_id, B.appt_obj_id, B.appointment_id, C.appointment_id, C.tc_appointment_id from B
join A on B.appt_obj_id = A.asn_id
join C on C.appointment_id = B.appointment_id
where C.appt_status < '9' and A.appointment_id is null;

--Update attempt that ends with SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

update asn set appoinmtent_id = ilm_appointments.tc_appointment_id
join ilm_appointment_objects on ilm_appointment_objects.appt_obj_id = asn.asn_id
join ilm_appointments on ilm_appointments.appointment_id = ilm_appointment_objects.appointment_id
where ilm_appointments.appt_status < '9' and asn.appointment_id is null;
```

The expected result is to update all `null` values for `A.appointment_id` to be updated with the values from `C.tc_appointment_id`.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE...JOIN` syntax is not supported in Oracle. You could use a correlated subquery instead.

Consider:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.appointment_id = (
    SELECT C.tc_appointment_id
    FROM B
    INNER JOIN C ON C.appointment_id = B.appointment_id
    WHERE B.appt_obj_id = A.asn_id
)
WHERE A.appointment_id IS NULL;
```

Beware that the subquery *must* return a unique record, otherwise you will get an error like "subquery returned more than one row". Given your sample data this seems to be the OK.